# Retrieve Image From HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, image

Hey, so I have some html ok, and inside it there's a couple of images. What I want to do is retrieve the location of the first image from the html. (get the first images url)

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) class you can put to use for that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at, [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Once you load the HTML into a `DOMDocument` you can easily traverse through the file and retrieve the first image url.

References:

- [`loadHTMLfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)
- [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)
- [`DOMNodeList#item`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php)

Answer (score 1):

You COULD use a regular expression (though html is NOT technically regex parseable as its not... regular): Read in the contents of the file, then use a regular expression to hopefully find the img tag and extract the src attribute. Definitely not the best solution, but a technically possible solution. I don't really recommend this.

Outside of that you may want to look into a PHP Document Object Model parser and find the first image node.

Comment: [This is why you should **never** use regex for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)